# Mist 0.9 Can't connect remote geth server

Tags: mist, private-blockchain

I setup a geth private blockchain with this command.

```
geth --dev --networkid 13  --rpc --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcport "8568" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/root/geth/chain" --port "30309" --identity "MyNode" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" console
```

And I test connect rpc port by curl, it is OK.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://x.x.x.x:8568
```

Then, I start mist by this command

```
./Mist --rpc http://x.x.x.x:8568

2017-07-28 11:33:16.171] [INFO] main - Running in production mode: true
[2017-07-28 11:33:16.175] [WARN] main - CONNECTING TO A NODE VIA HTTP INSTEAD OF IPCMAIN. THIS IS LESS SECURE!!!!
[2017-07-28 11:33:16.296] [INFO] main - Starting in Mist mode
[2017-07-28 11:33:27.290] [INFO] Db - Loading db: /Users/huxiangwei/Library/Application Support/Mist/mist.lokidb
[2017-07-28 11:33:27.304] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2017-07-28 11:33:27.305] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
[2017-07-28 11:33:27.379] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2017-07-28 11:33:30.031] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2017-07-28 11:33:30.040] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset
[2017-07-28 11:33:30.558] [INFO] ipcCommunicator - Backend language set to:  zh
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.269] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.352] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Meteor starting up...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.444] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.445] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving path to Eth client binary ...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.445] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Eth client binary path: /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/nodes/eth/mac-x64/eth
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.446] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.922] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.923] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.923] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.924] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.926] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.926] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.927] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.958] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2017-07-28 11:33:31.959] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.115] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://47.88.138.98:8568"}
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.328] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.328] [INFO] NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.329] [INFO] NodeSync - Starting sync loop
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.330] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://47.88.138.98:8568"}
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.700] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.952] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2017-07-28 11:33:32.953] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2017-07-28 11:33:34.880] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
[2017-07-28 11:33:52.730] [ERROR] main - Error starting up node and/or syncing Error: Couldn't start swarm process.
    at Timeout.error [as _onTimeout] (/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js:420:21)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
```

I hope to setup a private blockchain and use mist to test smart contract.
Could you give me some idea? thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest just to disable swarm like it described in the usage:

```
  --swarmurl              URL serving the Swarm HTTP API. If null, Mist will
                          open a local node.
                                 [string] [default: "http://localhost:8500"]
```

So, run mist with command line argument '--swarmurl "null"'.
E.g. for my mac env it look like:

```
/Applications/Ethereum\ Wallet.app/Contents/MacOS/Ethereum\ Wallet --rpc http://192.168.56.102:8080 --mode mist --node geth --network 15 --swarmurl "null"
```