# Can't launch Mist with testRPC

Tags: mist, testrpc, swarm

On Win10 I downloaded and installed truffle and trying to do their recent "pet-shop" tutorial. At the Dapp stage, didn't manage to work with Metamask as suggested and tried Mist instead. I have testRPC running and am launching Mist with --rpc http://localhost:8545. I get:

```
[2017-07-30 12:40:23.725] [INFO] main - Running in production mode: true
[2017-07-30 12:40:23.728] [WARN] main - CONNECTING TO A NODE VIA HTTP INSTEAD OF IPCMAIN. THIS IS LESS SECURE!!!!
[2017-07-30 12:40:23.993] [INFO] main - Starting in Mist mode
[2017-07-30 12:40:26.240] [INFO] Db - Loading db: C:\Users\Sorin\AppData\Roaming\Mist\mist.lokidb
[2017-07-30 12:40:26.258] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2017-07-30 12:40:26.259] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
[2017-07-30 12:40:26.312] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2017-07-30 12:40:28.440] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2017-07-30 12:40:28.480] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset
[2017-07-30 12:40:29.066] [INFO] ipcCommunicator - Backend language set to:  fr
[2017-07-30 12:40:29.393] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
[2017-07-30 12:40:29.923] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.
[2017-07-30 12:40:29.998] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Meteor starting up...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.061] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.069] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving path to Eth client binary ...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.071] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Eth client binary path: C:\Program Files\Mist\nodes\eth\win-x64\eth.exe
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.074] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.136] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.139] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.139] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.143] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.146] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.146] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.148] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.283] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.284] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.369] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://localhost:8545"}
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.391] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.393] [INFO] NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.395] [INFO] NodeSync - Starting sync loop
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.398] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://localhost:8545"}
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.412] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.435] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2017-07-30 12:40:30.438] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2017-07-30 12:40:51.958] [ERROR] main - Error starting up node and/or syncing Error: Couldn't start swarm process.
    at Timeout.error [as _onTimeout] (C:\Program Files\Mist\resources\app.asar\node_modules\swarm-js\lib\swarm.js:420:21)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
[2017-07-30 12:41:28.671] [INFO] NodeSync - Sync has been skipped
[2017-07-30 12:41:28.674] [INFO] NodeSync - Sync loop ended
```

There is another question with the same error but it has no answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered to this question there: I've already answered to this question there: [Mist 0.9 Can't connect remote geth server](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/mist-0-9-cant-connect-remote-geth-server)